# xtype in Extjs4 creates same id

Tags: extjs

In extjs4 if I have a button as follows:

```
Ext.define('Pandora.view.MyButton', {
extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
alias: 'widget.mybutton',
text: 'click me',
id: 'butid'
```

});

If I use it in viewport as follows:

```
                    {
                      xtype: 'panel',
                      id: 'panelid',
                      title: 'One tab',
                      html: '<p>what is this </p>'
                    },
                    {
                      xtype: "mybutton"

                    },
                    {
                      xtype: "mybutton"
                    }
```

This will create two buttons with same id (which is not W3C recommended), and it could produce weird behavior. In order to reuse same button multiple times in application is it recommended to use xtype without providing id (In which case Extjs will create its own).

Answer (score 5):

> This will create two buttons with same id

yes this is true for your situation because you have hardcoded the id config when creating the class

```
Ext.define('Pandora.view.MyButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    alias: 'widget.mybutton',
    text: 'click me',
    id: 'butid'     <=========
});
```

from ExtJS4 docs:

> Note that this id will also be used as the element id for the
>   containing HTML element that is rendered to the page for this
>   component. This allows you to write id-based CSS rules to style the
>   specific instance of this component uniquely, and also to select
>   sub-elements using this component's id as the parent.

**Reference:**  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button

Comment: You mean Extjs is not following W3C standards. Secondly if you have simple html page with two elements with same id, only the first one works (is refered by getElementById). How is Extjs managing multiple ID in same DOM.

Comment: well, you'd be the one not following W3C standards by not letting the framework generate the id upon rendering duplicate components. components can be accessed using css selectors and also the container specific property 'itemId'

Comment: yeah as stated in above comment its developers responsibility to provide different ids to every component, or else don't specify id and ExtJS knows W3C standards so it will create unique id for each component using Ext.id() function

Comment: @user1296632 Ext makes it clear that you shouldn't hard code IDs if a component can be used more than once, just like DOM ids. I complemented SilentSakky's  answer by suggesting a way to get around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IDs mean you can't have two on one page, they are mapped 1 to 1 with DOM ids. Therefore, you can't define a class that is going to be reused to have a hard coded id. If you need to find all elements of your class use [`Ext.ComponentQuery.query`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query) passing it the xtype you're looking for

```
// You should also pass in a root component to start the search from
// but it's optional
var buttons = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mybutton', root);
```

Now you can remove your id from the class definition